# GCC option -save-temps numbers after header files

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

When I compile code on gcc with the option `-save-temps`, the resulting `filename.i` which stores the preprocessed output has lines such as:

```
#44 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
struct _IO_FILE;
```

where `44` is the the line number in `/usr/include/stdio.h` that includes the code `struct _IO_FILE;`. I would like to know what are the `3 4` after the header name. I've searched in `man gcc` but haven't found an   explanation.

Comment: I recommend [the online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html#Preprocessor-Output:

> Source file name and line number information is conveyed by lines of the form
>
> ```
> # linenum filename flags
> ```
>
> These are called *linemarkers*. They are inserted as needed into the output (but never within a string or character constant). They mean that the following line originated in file *filename* at line *linenum*. *filename* will never contain any non-printing characters; they are replaced with octal escape sequences.
>
> After the file name comes zero or more flags, which are `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`. If there are multiple flags, spaces separate them. Here is what the flags mean:
>
> - `1` - This indicates the start of a new file.
> - `2` - This indicates returning to a file (after having included another file).
> - `3` - This indicates that the following text comes from a system header file, so certain warnings should be suppressed.
> - `4` - This indicates that the following text should be treated as being wrapped in an implicit `extern "C"` block.